# How to override Laravel's language files with your package language

Tags: laravel, package, translation

I am trying to override the default laravel english language package under `resources/lang/en`with my languages from my package.

The package just publishes its own language files to e.g. `resources/lang/vendor/*package-name*/de` and has the same files in it as the laravel standard lang file like `validation.php` or `auth.php`.

Is there a way to tell Laravel to use these package translations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages#translations),

> Package translation files are typically referenced using a
>   double-colon syntax.

While loading your translations in your package's Service Provider's `boot` method, you need to tell Laravel about where it's located. So let's say your package's name is `acme`, you would have something like this.

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/translations', 'acme');
}
```

Then to load the translation, you would do something like this:

```
trans('acme::file.line');
```

Edit: If you want to provide Custom Validation Messages, you would need to add a `messages()` method in your [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests). For example:

```
public function messages() 
{
    return [
        'field' => trans('acme::validation.field')
    ];
}
```

If you are manually creating Validator instances, you could just do this:

```
$messages = [
    'field' => trans('acme::validation.field')
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

Edit: Since `resources/lang/en/validation.php` contains an array of key value pairs, you could just replace the contents of the file with this:

```
<?php

return trans('acme::validation');
```

and assuming that your package's validation file is returning an array of key-value pairs, that should do the trick.

Comment: I did that. But I need to tell Laravel that it should primary refer to the published language files. 
If I make a request in my application now and validate it I get the error in english.

Comment: Is there no way to tell Laravel to globally use the package's lang files? Because otherwise I have to write custom messages for every request I validate in my package.

Comment: As far as I understand, no. You can take a look at this [trait](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/FormatsMessages.html). The reference to the validation file is hard-coded.

Comment: @MangoD, found a little trick to get it done, which should work.